# I am unable to understand code of UVA 10242 Fourth Point !! despite trying for hours

Tags: c++, computational-geometry

I have been trying to understand solution code of this problem given by Isanchez_Aguilar. I am having trouble in understanding function inline Vector operator+ & — both. I am also not able to get what `Vector():x(0), y(0) {}` & `Vector(Double _x, Double _y):x(_x), y(_y) {}` are supposed to mean.

Isanchez_Aguilar's solution code is below and you can also use this link:https://github.com/isanchez-aguilar/UVa-Solutions/blob/master/10242%20-%20Fourth%20Point%20!!.cpp
`

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

typedef double Double;

const Double EPS = 1e-3;

inline Double isEqual(Double a, Double b) { return fabs(a - b) < EPS; }

class Vector
{
public:
Double x;
Double y;

Vector():x(0), y(0) {}

Vector(Double _x, Double _y):x(_x), y(_y) {}

inline bool operator==(const Vector& a) const { return isEqual(x, a.x) and isEqual(y, a.y); }

inline Vector operator+(const Vector& a)
{
    Vector b;
    b.x = x + a.x;
    b.y = y + a.y;
    
    return b;
}

inline Vector operator-(const Vector& a)
{
    Vector b;
    b.x = x - a.x;
    b.y = y - a.y;
    
    return b;
}
};

Vector points[4];



int main(void){
ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0);
cin.tie(0);

cout.precision(3);
cout.setf(ios::fixed);

while (cin >> points[0].x >> points[0].y)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < 4; ++i)
        cin >> points[i].x >> points[i].y;

    int a = 1;
    int b = 0;
    int c = 2;

    if (points[0] == points[2])
    {
        a = 0;
        b = 1;
        c = 3;
    }
    else if (points[0] == points[3])
    {
        a = 0;
        b = 1;
        c = 2;

    }
    else if (points[1] == points[2])
        c = 3;
    Vector p = points[c] + points[b] - points[a];

    cout << p.x << " " << p.y << "\n";
}
return 0;
}   
`
```

Comment: Vector():x(0), y(0) {}" is a constructor of a class Vector which initializes its members x, y to  0. And Vector(Double _x, Double _y):x(_x), y(_y) {} is a constructor that initializes its members x to the value of _x and y to the value of _y

Answer (score 1):

The `+` and `-` functions are to use `+`, `-` operators on vectors, since you can't use them on objects unless they are defined for the object.

They simply say that, for Vectors `a, b: a + b = {a.x + b.x, a.y + b.y}`.

The `Vector():x(0), y(0) {}` & `Vector(Double _x, Double _y):x(_x), y(_y) {}` are constructors.

The first is the default, setting `x`, `y` to `0`.

The second is used to set the values manually, e.g. `Vector a(xi, yi)`